# Error 503 while accessing /bigdata/dataloader at wikidata local

Tags: jetty, sparql, wikidata, blazegraph

I get this error when running the following command:

```
$ ./loadRestAPI.sh -n wdq -d `pwd`/data/split/wikidump-000000001.ttl.gz
```

See https://github.com/wikimedia/wikidata-query-rdf/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md

```
Loading with properties...
quiet=false
verbose=0
closure=false
durableQueues=true
#Needed for quads
#defaultGraph=
com.bigdata.rdf.store.DataLoader.flush=false
com.bigdata.rdf.store.DataLoader.bufferCapacity=100000
com.bigdata.rdf.store.DataLoader.queueCapacity=10
#Namespace to load
namespace=wdq
#Files to load
fileOrDirs=/data/split
#Property file (if creating a new namespace)
propertyFile=/home/tsc/projects/TestSPARQL/wikidata-query-rdf-0.2.1/dist/target/service-0.2.1/RWStore.properties
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1"/>
<title>Error 503 </title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>HTTP ERROR: 503</h2>
<p>Problem accessing /bigdata/dataloader. Reason:
<pre>    Service Unavailable</pre></p>
<hr /><i><small>Powered by Jetty://</small></i>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The error message is in the HTML: `HTTP ERROR: 503 Service Unavailable` Are you sure that your Blazegraph is running?

Comment: I guess, I can connect to http://localhost:9999/bigdata and for ex. I can access to the Query or Update in the menu .

Comment: Look into the script and see which URL it tries to call. It calls `http://localhost:9999/bigdata/dataloader`

Comment: You solved it when asking if I am connect or not. I run again Blazegraph but with 'sudo' and it works, thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works when runing Blazegraph with 'sudo'...

Comment: I wouldn't recommend running application as big as Blazegraph under root user though... Check permissions on directories/files involved.